# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp\www\midtermexam\update.php on line 78

Tags: php, mysql

Please help, this is my midterm exam, i got stucked for three days :(

```
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE tbl_students 
                                         SET studName=:studname, 
                                             studCourse=:studcourse,
                                             studAddress=:studaddress,
                                             studGender=:studgender,
                                             studPic=:studpic 
                                       WHERE studID=:studid');
            $stmt->bindParam(':studname',$studname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':studcourse',$studcourse);
            $stmt->bindParam(':studpic',$studpic);
            $stmt->bindParam(':studid',$studid);

            if($stmt->execute()){
```

Comment: what about studaddress and studgender in the bindings?

Comment: What isn't there to understand? The error is quite clear, try counting the number of fields you are trying to set, with the amount of data you are giving the query, I count 6 fields but only 4 variables being bound.

Answer (score 0):

Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens!  Hint: "studAddress"

Answer (score 0):

I see six distinct colon variables (like `:studname`) in the SQL and only four bindings.

You appear to have missed `:studaddress` and `:studgender` so they either need to be bound or removed from the SQL.

Comment: str_replace("midterm","homework","midterm")